# I want to add my userid in my link but link shoud be remin same

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add my userid in my link but link shoud be same and clickable.

Here's my code:

```
    buo.getShortUrl(with: lp) { (url, error) in

        //url = "myrmndtest5.test-app.link/aLyM9DI2cS"     
        let domain = url
        let parameter:AnyObject = "?id=5" as AnyObject
        let testurl:NSURL = NSURL(string: "\(domain)) \(parameter)")!

        print(testurl)
    }
```

it showing me nil value. is there any code for append both

Comment: You can't add like that a space in a URL. So `"\(domain)) \(parameter)"` should at least be `"\(domain))\(parameter)". Also you could use QueryItems to construct your URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [url components](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents) instead. You can add query items to a string that has already the scheme, host, and path, like so:

```
let url = "https://myrmndtest5.test-app.link/aLyM9DI2cS"
var components = URLComponents(string: url)!
let queryItemId = URLQueryItem(name: "id", value: "5")

components.queryItems = [queryItemId]

print(components.url!)
```

---

(*PS: I am force-unwrapping for brevity*)

Comment: @Prasann what is the exact `url` string? The one in the answer uses the string indicated in your question.

Comment: sorry sir i just forgot to add this one real url : "https://myrmndtest5.test-app.link/J9xHJXf2cS"

Comment: thanks a lot sir ... i am just fresher in swift can you tell me how to improve my swift means suggest some documentation or tutorial series

Comment: @Prasann You can't go wrong with the [official documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html). There are some free episodes [here](https://www.pointfree.co/). Personally, reading some of the answers by 
[Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r) is a daily joy.